# Plot that shows that largest root tends to 1

Tags: pgfplots

I am considering x^{i+2}-x^{i+1}-1.

As i goes to infinity, the largest root tends to 1.

I would like to have a plot in latex, for example with pgfplots, that shows this, maybe one could plot the graphs for i=1, i=10, i=100 or something like that in order to see that.

Unfortunately I do not know how to plot this is in a good way such that one can see the largest roots and that it tends to 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the math first: your equation is equivalent to `x^2 - x = 1/x^i`. So, on the same axis, draw the graph of `y = x^2 -x` and `y = 1/x^i` for some values of `i`, for example, `i = 1,10,50,200`. The `x`-coordinates of the intersections are the largest roots of the orginal equation (You should be able to prove this).[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [xmin=.9,xmax=2,
      ymax=1,
      ymin=-.1,
    ]
    \addplot[thick,black,samples=100,domain=.99:2] {x^2 - x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.25] {$x^2 - x$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,red,samples=100,domain=1:2]  {1/x}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.2] {$i=1$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,green,samples=100,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^10}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.3] {$i=10$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,cyan,samples=200,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^50}
    node[above,sloped,pos=.52] {$i=50$}
    ;
    \addplot[thick,blue,samples=300,domain=.99:2]  {1/x^200}
    ;
    \node[blue,rotate=270] at (axis cs:.96,.2) {$i=200$};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The intersection points of $x^2-x$ and $1/x^i$ are the roots of the original equation. Why do you say that the x-coordinates are automatically the largest root?

Comment: The curves are `y = x^2 - x` and `y = 1/x^i`. So the intersection points are of the form `(x0,y0)` where `x0` is *a root* of the original equation. From the graph, you can see that, in the domain `(0,+\infty)`, the original equation has only one root. Therefore, `x0` must be the largest root.

Comment: Okay, now I got what you mean, thanks a lot for this nice picture!

Comment: Can I use this (slightly modificated) for my document? Is that okay for you?

Comment: Sure, you are free to use it.